# Yocto Poky-Pyro bbappend file for init-ifupdown is not replacing /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am using Yocto poky-pyro on Ubuntu 16.04. I want to replace the /etc/network/interfaces file on the resulting image root file system, so I added a bbappend recipe in my meta-company directory that also contains other package recipes that are built properly.

```
user@BuildMachine:~/bbb/meta-bbb/recipes-custom/init-ifupdown$ tree
.
├── init-ifupdown_1.0
│   └── interfaces
└── init-ifupdown_1.0.bbappend

1 directory, 2 files
```

The bbappend file looks like this:

```
# Extend the base recipe search path to $HERE/init-ifupdown
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/init-ifupdown-1.0:"
```

And the interfaces file in that directory looks like this:

```
user@BuildMachine:~/bbb/meta-bbb/recipes-custom/init-ifupdown$ cat init-ifupdown_1.0/interfaces 
# Configure Loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Configure WiFi Infrastructure
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp

 # Configure WiFi Hotspot
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet static  
    address 172.24.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 172.24.1.0
    broadcast 172.24.1.255
```

After I build my image and look in the work build directory for the init-ifupdown package, I see that the wrong "interfaces" file is there and it matches what is in the image:

```
user@BuildMachine:~/bbb/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/init-ifupdown/1.0-r7$ ls interfaces 
interfaces
user@BuildMachine:~/bbb/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/init-ifupdown/1.0-r7$ cat interfaces 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

### wired, static
#auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet static
#   address 192.168.10.33
#   netmask 255.255.255.0
#   gateway 192.168.10.1
```

How can I get my bbappend file to take affect and deploy my custom interfaces file?

Comment: was working for me. ensure that you include your layer in the bblayers.conf an do a clean before you rebuilt id: I use bitbake -c clean <imagename> and then bitbake <imagename>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `interfaces` file is machine specific, thus there are quite likely already another `interfaces` file that's behind a `machine override`.

Put the file in a subdirectory `init-ifupdown_1.0/${MACHINE}`. That will ensure that your `interfaces` file will only be picked up by your machine, it'll also give it priority for your machine.

Comment: For the record, I just found where the documentation explains this: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#best-practices-to-follow-when-creating-layers